# Mapbox Vector Source / Fill Layer problem using Flutter and two different packages

Tags: flutter, vector, mapbox, layer

I have a problem that I am not able to describe so I have taken a video of the issue. In the video I am clicking forward one 'frame' at a time and you can see the layer loads then it seems like the fill is applied/changed(?) after a delay. I have tried two different packages and it occurs with both of them. So I'm assuming the problem is my code as I am no expert! It happens on the emulator and real device.

https://youtube.com/shorts/1jT5OKuSISQ

The code below is using the mapbox_gl package, but this issue also occurs with the official mapbox_maps_flutter package. I have raised an issue in the mapbox_gl GitHub, but have had no reply.

```
void _addRadarLayer (String id) {
 
    this.controller.addSource(
      'composite$id',
      VectorSourceProperties(
        url: radarCapability.data.rain[frame].url,
        minzoom: 3,
        maxzoom: 10,
      ),
    );

    this.controller.addFillLayer(
      'composite$id',
      'radarLayer$id',
      const FillLayerProperties(
          fillColor:
          [
            Expressions.interpolate,
            ['linear'],
            ['get', 'value'],
            0,
            'hsla(240, 100, 98, 0)',
            0.4,
            '#f5f5ff',
            1.6,
            '#b4b4ff',
            3.1,
            '#7878ff',
            4.7,
            '#1414ff',
            7,
            '#00d8c3',
            10.5,
            '#009690',
            15.8,
            '#006666',
            23.7,
            '#ffff00',
            35.5,
            '#ffc800',
            53.4,
            '#ff9600',
            80.1,
            '#ff6400',
            120.3,
            '#ff0000',
            180.5,
            '#c80000',
            271.1,
            '#780000',
            406.9,
            '#280000'
          ],
      ),
      sourceLayer: id,
      minzoom: 3,
      maxzoom: 10,
    );

  }
```

In the video, clicking the button removes the layer & source, then re-adds the source and layer based on the incremented 'frame' variable. Happy to post more code if needed.

Hopefully someone can assist.